# Android CWAC-Adapter : why registerDataSetObserver in Constructor?

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

As the title says, I am having difficulty in understanding the use of `registerDataSetObserver` in the `Constructor` of `cwac-adapter`

```
 /**
  * Constructor wrapping a supplied ListAdapter
  */
  public AdapterWrapper(ListAdapter wrapped) {
    super();

    this.wrapped=wrapped;

    wrapped.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
      public void onChanged() {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

      public void onInvalidated() {
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
      }
    });
  }
```

Doesn't this create recursive calls to the `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

My understanding is that, `notifyDataSetChanged()` will call `onChanged` of all the registered observers of an `Adapter`. So, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the `onChanged()` will create recursive calls.

Is my understanding wrong? if yes, what exactly is going on here? if not, whats the use of having such recursive calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two adapters, let's call them List and Wrapper. When you got changes in the list, you notify wrapper. No more code is executed.